# SQL Server Constraints

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

I want to create a check constraint in SQL Server which will allow be ensure the inserts into a column meet these rules

- The entry must be 10 or 11 characters long
- Characters 1 to 9 inclusive have to be digits
- Character 10 has to be a letter
- Character 11 if used has to be Z.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this...

```
ALTER TABLE TableName 
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_Const CHECK
                        ( 
                             LEFT(ColumnName ,9) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
                         AND SUBSTRING(ColumnName , 10, 1) NOT LIKE '%[^a-Z]%'
                         AND ( (LEN (ColumnName) = 10)
                               OR 
                               (LEN (ColumnName) = 11 AND RIGHT(ColumnName,1) = 'Z')
                              ) 
                        )
```

### Test

```
CREATE TABLE TableName (ColumnName VARCHAR(11))
GO

INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnName)  VALUES ('123193123AZ')   -- PASS
INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnName)  VALUES ('123193123A')    -- PASS
INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnName)  VALUES ('123A93123A')    -- FAIL
INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnName)  VALUES ('123793123')     -- FAIL
INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnName)  VALUES ('123093123AJ')   -- FAIL
```

Comment: I think `AND LEN (ColumnName) IN (10,11)` is redundant

Comment: True was going through the long list of Ifs and buts and lost the track :)

Answer (score -2):

My try:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName (col VARCHAR(11))
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename ADD CONSTRAINT CK_tablename_columnname
    CHECK ((len(col)=10 or len(col)=11) AND (len(col)>=10 AND PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',col)=10) AND ((len(col)=11 AND substring(col,11,1)='Z') OR len(col)=10))


INSERT INTO TableName (col)  VALUES ('123193123AZ')   -- PASS
INSERT INTO TableName (col)  VALUES ('123193123A')    -- PASS
INSERT INTO TableName (col)  VALUES ('123A93123A')    -- FAIL
INSERT INTO TableName (col)  VALUES ('123793123')     -- FAIL
INSERT INTO TableName (col)  VALUES ('123093123AJ')   -- Fail
```

1)The entry must be 10 or 11 characters long
(len(col)=10 or len(col)=11)

2)Character 10 has to be a letter
PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',col)=10
PATINDEX gives you the position of first non numeric char.

If your 10th position has char then above condition will be passed.
In all other case input is wrong.(i.e char occurs before 10th char in your input)

3)Character 11 if used has to be Z.
len(col)=11 AND substring(col1,11,1)='Z'

Comment: Whoever putting downvote, pls suggest where i went wrong which is helpful for me to correct and it will give multiple solutions to the one who raised the ques here. Please see my edited portion with input and output.